# SelectSingleNode() returns null

Tags: c#, xml

Thanks for reading my thread. I am trying to load the value of FFTExe from following xml file, but it node returns null.

Here is the code I use to read the xml

```
    const string CMD_FFT = "/Command/FFTExe";    

    string strFile = Application.Current.Resources["ApplicationSettingsFolder"].ToString() + "\\CommandList.xml";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(strFile);

    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode(CMD_FFT);
    if (null != node)  //<-----problem occurs here, node is null!!!
        GetAttribute(node, doc, "value", ref FFTExeFile);
```

Here is my xml file, where I want to extract "D:\fft\fft.exe" from entry FFTExe's value

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<CommandList>
    <Command name="Capture" guid="30db4357-7508-46c9-84eb-3ca0900aa4c5" panel=".\Modules\ExperimentSettingsViewer.dll" description="">
        <Experiment value="" />
        <OutputPath value="" />
    </Command>
    <Command name="Run ImageJ Macro" guid="C1391459-132F-45ea-AE72-D7BEB2BD8086" panel=".\Modules\Panel.dll" description="">
        <Macro value="" />
        <DataFolder value="D:\out\" />
        <FFTExe value="D:\fft\fft.exe" />
        <Headless value="1" />
    </Command>
</CommandList>
```

Thank you any suggestions.

I also tried

```
const string CMD_FFT = "/Command/Command/FFTExe";
```

and

```
const string CMD_FFT = "FFTExe";
```

no luck

Comment: Have you also tried `/CommandList/Command/FFTExe`?

Comment: Yeah it works. Can you post your answer so I can accept it? Thansk!

Comment: good to hear that it helped. I've added an answer.

Comment: Have a look into `XDocument` as well, as you'll find the API is much cleaner. `XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(file); string fftexe = xdoc.Desecendents("FFTExe").First().Attribute("value") as string`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your XPath to `/CommandList/Command/FFTExe` as a single slash at the beginning means to start at the root so you need to include the `CommandList` root element.

For additional info on XPath see this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp).